# Polymer layout attribute to stretch custom element over whole viewport

Tags: html, layout, polymer

I am currently having my first tries with Polymer.

What I have is a custom polymer element nested in a `core-animated-pages` element on the main page.

The sources are:

*index.html*

```
<core-header-panel>

    <core-toolbar>
        [...]
    </core-toolbar>

    <core-animated-pages transitions="slide-from-right">
        [...]
        <section>
            <contact-page></contact-page>
        </section>
    </core-animated-pages>

</core-header-panel>
```

*contact-page.html*

```
<polymer-element name="contact-page">
<template>
    [...]
    <div layout horizontal start-justified>

        <div class="placeholder">
        </div>

        <div class="contact-box" layout horizontal center-justified flex three>
            <div class="form-container" layout vertical>
                <h2>Contact</h2>
                <paper-input class="additional-dist" floatingLabel label="Name"></paper-input>
                <paper-input id="mail" floatingLabel label="Mail"></paper-input>
                <div layout horizontal>
                    <paper-input id="msg" multiline maxRows="4" rows="4" floatingLabel label="Message" flex></paper-input>
                </div>
                <paper-button label="Submit" on-tap="{{submit}}" self-end></paper-button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
[...]
</template>
[...]
</polymer-element>
```

The HTML file currently looks [like this in *Chrome 37*.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40gAw.png)

Now what I'd like to have is that the yellow bar (`placeholder`) is vertically stretched over the whole viewport, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzdbm.png).

Unfortunately I can't figure out which polymer `layout attribute`s I have to use to achieve this and in which tags I have to put them. Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited to incorporate feedback from sjmiles:**

Give this a shot:

```
<body fullbleed layout vertical>

  <polymer-element name="x-foo" layout vertical>
    <template>
      <style>
        #header {
          background: tomato;
        }
        #col {
          background: yellow;
        }
      </style>
      <div id="header" layout horizontal>
        Header
      </div>
      <div id="main" flex layout horizontal>
        <div flex id="col">Col</div>
        <div flex layout vertical>
          <div>Section 1</div>
          <div>Section 2</div>
          <div>Section 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({

      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>

  <x-foo flex></x-foo>

</body>
```

I'm using the [`fullbleed` attribute to set the body to `100vh`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html#full-bleed-ltbody) and telling it to layout its children vertically using flexbox. Then setting `x-foo` to `flex` so it fills the screen. Then it's just a matter of getting the right children to flex.

Here's [a jsbin to preview](http://jsbin.com/ceweho/edit).

Comment: IMO, rather than mixing % and layout, you are better off using layout attributes for the whole stack. Iow, `<body fullbleed vertical layout><x-foo flex></x-foo>...`. http://jsbin.com/dumow/1/edit

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. This works fine for me as long as the custom element is a direct child of `<body>`. But when I put the custom element into a `<core-header-panel>`, it breaks the layout completely. Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: Got it. Adding the `fit` layout attribute to the content of the `core-header-panel` (which was in my case a `core-animated-pages`) and to my custom element did the trick for me.